# hbase cannot connect to hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am running an hdfs instance in pseudo-distributed mode, and tried to make another hbase instance connected to it on the same server. Logs in hadoop are fine, but I constantly got the connection failure  in hbase' log

==================================================================================

```
2012-05-01 10:49:07,212 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2012-05-01 10:49:07,213 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x13708dc552d0001 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:567)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1119)

2012-05-01 10:49:08,882 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2012-05-01 10:49:08,882 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x13708dc552d0001 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:567)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1119)
```

==================================================================================

Configuration of core-site.xml@hadoop

```
<configuration>

<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Configuration of hbase-site.xml@hbase

```
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
   <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.replication</name>
   <value>1</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

I also tried to replace localhost with the actual ip of the server, but got the same error.

Comment: Looks like a problem with ZooKeeper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Hbase cannot find the zookeeper quorum, you have to set the hbase.zookeeper.quorum property in hbase-site.xml. Also check if classpath is set properly or not, check this doc out http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/package-summary.html#classpath

Comment: I think by default zookeeper quorum is localhost, so I thought it was fine I did set it in pseudo-distributed mode. But anyway I explicitly set zookeeper quorum to be my local hostname and set the clientport to be 2222. With these setup, I still got the same issue of "connection refused" :-(

Comment: Even after setting the Zk parameter if you see in the logs that it tries to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, that would indicate that Hbase cannot see the chnages you made in the config file. Check the classpath settings from the link I put.

Comment: It is not about setting up zookeeper. It is my 0.90 HBase is using a branch versioned hadoop jar, which is incompatible with 0.20.2 hadoop release. Whoever runs into this issue, please consider referring to this: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:I_-a-FWWlWkJ:www.michael-noll.com/blog/2011/04/14/building-an-hadoop-0-20-x-version-for-hbase-0-90-2/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Answer (score 1):

- First, you need to make sure your hbase master node is running, you can use `jps` to check.

If it is not running, you can run it by `start-hbase.sh` command or `hbase master start`.
And then check its status by other commands, like `netstat -an | grep 9000`

- Second, if the previous method does not work, check your firewall configuration such as iptables and SELinux. 
  Use `sudo iptables -L` to check your iptables configuration. You can disable the iptables by `sudo service iptables stop` command under redhat based linux systems.

Use `getenforce` to check if SElinux is in `enforcing` mode.

- Third, check the system configuration, for example, `ssh` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the core hadoop jar in the $HBASE_HOME/bin/lib/hadoop-{{version}}core.jar with the one in the $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-{{version}}core.jar
I was running into the same problem when I tried to install hbase 0.92 from hbase 0.90-xxx which was working fine, i replaced the hbase-env.sh and hbase-site.xml from the old hbase to the new but forgot to copy the hadoop core jar.

Comment: I think I tried to replace the hadoop core jar, but it turned out that hadoop and hbase cannot talk to each other happily with this method. i ended with using hadoop 1.0.0 and hbase 0.92, which have consistent hadoop core jars.

Comment: No I meant on the system where Hadoop is running if it is running, then the same jar needs to go into Hbase lib, to avoid version incompatibility. So on my system, i was running hadoop and hbase both on the same node. Hence I mentioned this way.
Also, I just switched myself to hadoop-1.0.1 with hbase-0.95, which gels well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm always suspicious when I see localhost in a config. Also when you use localhost, then it becomes very difficult (to impossible) to access any services from the psuedo distributed system from a host other than the one you are running on.

You did say you tried the IP address, but you might want to make sure its the IP address that the node really thinks its at.

Check the zookeeper logs from when it starts up and see what IP address it "thinks" its at. There should be a line like:

```
2012-01-31 09:32:46,083 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:host.name=ip-10-8-127-58.ec2.internal
```

Then use the value of host.name as the value for all places in ALL Hadodop, HBase, Hive, Zookeeper, etc config files that need a hostname (assuming they are all on the same machine as you said you are in psuedo-distributed mode)

Also you did not show your hbase.zookeeper.quorum setting in hbase-site.xml. That is where hbase gets its knowledge of the zookeeper's address

```
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>ip-10-8-127-58.ec2.internal</value>
  </property>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments! What you suggested usually happen for setting up hadoop/hbase on Amazon EC2 boxes as your example hbase-site.xml suggested:-) My situation was different. Failure to make hadoop and hbase talk to each other happily was solely because they dont share the same hadoop core jar file. I therefore strongly suggest use hadoop-1.0.0 and hbase-0.92 for setting up a hbase cluster. This way if you had problem making them talk to other, at least you know it is not due to the version inconsistency:-)